# Use a dictionary-comprehension to return country as key and a total number of cities for country as value

Tags: python, tuples, dictionary-comprehension

I'm using a dict-comprehension to return country names as unique key and want value to be number of cities in that country. How do I count the number of cities from list of tuples?

```
country_city_tuples= [('Netherlands', 'Alkmaar'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Tilburg'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Den Bosch'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Eindhoven'),
                      ('Spain', 'Madrid'),
                      ('Spain', 'Barcelona'),
                      ('Spain', 'Cordoba'),
                      ('Spain', 'Toledo'),
                      ('Italy', 'Milano'),
                      ('Italy', 'Roma')]

country_names = { 

}
```

Expect result to be: `{'Italy': 2 , 'Netherlands': 4, 'Spain': 4}`

Comment: "I'm using a dict-comprehension to return country names" - where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract out the names of the countries from the list of tuples using `zip` and then use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to counter the frequency of country names

```
from collections import Counter

country_city_tuples= [('Netherlands', 'Alkmaar'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Tilburg'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Den Bosch'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Eindhoven'),
                      ('Spain', 'Madrid'),
                      ('Spain', 'Barcelona'),
                      ('Spain', 'Cordoba'),
                      ('Spain', 'Toledo'),
                      ('Italy', 'Milano'),
                      ('Italy', 'Roma')]

#Extract out country names using zip and list unpacking
country_names, _ = zip(*country_city_tuples)

#Count the number of countries using Counter
print(dict(Counter(country_names)))
```

To do it without using `collections`, we can use a dictionary to collect the frequencies

```
country_city_tuples= [('Netherlands', 'Alkmaar'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Tilburg'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Den Bosch'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Eindhoven'),
                      ('Spain', 'Madrid'),
                      ('Spain', 'Barcelona'),
                      ('Spain', 'Cordoba'),
                      ('Spain', 'Toledo'),
                      ('Italy', 'Milano'),
                      ('Italy', 'Roma')]

#Extract out country names using zip and list unpacking
country_names, _ = zip(*country_city_tuples)

result = {}

#Count each country
for name in country_names:
    result.setdefault(name,0)
    result[name] += 1

print(result)
```

The output will be same in both cases

```
{'Netherlands': 4, 'Spain': 4, 'Italy': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

country_names  = defaultdict(int)
for i in country_city_tuples:
    country_names[i[0]]+=1

country_names
defaultdict(int, {'Netherlands': 4, 'Spain': 4, 'Italy': 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
l = set(i[0] for i in country_city_tuples)
d = {}
for i in l:
   d[i] = sum([1 for j in country_city_tuples if j[0]==i])
```

**Output** :

```
{'Italy': 2, 'Netherlands': 4, 'Spain': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `sum` with a generator that returns 1 if the country name matches the country being checked, otherwise 0:

```
{name: sum(1 if c[0] == name else 0
           for c in country_city_tuples)
 for name in set(c[0] for c in country_city_tuples)}
```

You can also use `dict.get`:

```
r = {}
for name, city in country_city_tuples:
    r.get(name, 0) += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

without using `defaultdict` and other modules

```
country_city_tuples= [('Netherlands', 'Alkmaar'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Tilburg'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Den Bosch'),
                      ('Netherlands', 'Eindhoven'),
                      ('Spain', 'Madrid'),
                      ('Spain', 'Barcelona'),
                      ('Spain', 'Cordoba'),
                      ('Spain', 'Toledo'),
                      ('Italy', 'Milano'),
                      ('Italy', 'Roma')]

country_names ={}
for i in country_city_tuples:
    try:
        if country_names[i[0]]:
            country_names[i[0]]+=1
    except:
        country_names[i[0]]=1
print(country_names)

#output {'Netherlands': 4, 'Spain': 4, 'Italy': 2}
```